# how to call lwc function in XMLHttpRequest (xhr) post request methods

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

My code working fine for post the data but when i call success toast in onreadystatechange  its not working , i don't know what i miss and also lwc track variable not working in this function.

```
senddatawithxa() {

    console.log(progressBar);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "https://zinoui.com/demo/progress-bar/upload.php";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("token", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            showToast('File Uploaded', this.file.name + '- Uploaded Successfully!!!', 'success');
            showLoadingSpinner = false;
            fileName = '';
            isTrue = false;
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(json);

        }
    };
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        'image': encodeURIComponent(this.fileContents),
        'filename': this.fileName,
        'filetype': this.filetype,
        'patientId': this.recordId
    }
    );
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var ratio = Math.floor((e.loaded / e.total) * 100) + '%';
            console.log(ratio);

        }
    }
    xhr.upload.onloadstart = function (e) {
        //progress = 0;
        console.log(e);
    }
    xhr.upload.onloadend = function (e) {
        //console.log(e);
        progress = 100;

    }
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Comment: Why XMLHttpRequest in 2020? Why not [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

Comment: i need progress bar for uploading image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing's working because you're using the wrong `this`. When you use a normal `function`, `this` changes depending on what's calling the function. In this case, the XMLHttpRequest object. As such, you lose access to anything not directly in its closure, including class variables. To fix this, either `bind()` to the class, or just use an "[arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)":

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        this.showToast('File Uploaded', this.file.name + '- Uploaded Successfully!!!', 'success');
        // ... omitted ... //
    }
};
```

...

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = e => {
  if(e.lengthComputable) {
    // ... omitted ... //
  }
};
```

Also, note that to access class-level variables and methods, you must use `this`.

```
xhr.upload.onloadstart = e => {
    this.progress = 0;
    console.log(e);
};
```

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Comment: how can i know about this , is there any documentation

Comment: @RijwanMohammed You might be looking for [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (no pun intended, honest).